# About the concatination in string

Tags: c#

My problem is i am not able to concatenate emailtext in the place of Ms. Susan.

Please Help me in concatinating nameentry in the place of Ms. Susan

```
    void Sendbutton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

            var nametext = nameentry.Text;
            var emailtext = emailentry.Text;
            var subjecttext = subjectentry.Text;
            var messagetext = messageeditor.Text;


        try
        {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailtext);
            mail.To.Add("jatin.kapoor@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = subjecttext;
            string htmlString = @"<html>
                  <body>
                  <p>Dear Ms. Susan,</p>
                  <p>Thank you for your letter of yesterday inviting me to come for an interview on Friday afternoon, 5th July, at 2:30.
                          I shall be happy to be there as requested and will bring my diploma and other papers with me.</p>
                  <p>Sincerely,<br>-Jack</br></p>
                  </body>
                  </html>
                 ";
```

Comment: What error do you get - if any? What do you expect?

Comment: There were no errors i was just trying to mention the name of the sender of the mail in place of Ms. Susan. So who so ever the sender's name is it should reflect in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick for you:

```
        string htmlString = @"<html><body><p> Dear" 
                            + nametext 
                            + @",</p><p>"
                            + emailtext 
                            + @"</p><p>Sincerely,<br>-Jack</br></p></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
string nametext = nameentry.Text;
string htmlString = $@"<html>
                          <body>
                              <p>Dear {nametext},</p>
                              <p>Thank you for your letter of yesterday inviting me to come for an interview on Friday afternoon, 5th July, at 2:30.
                                 I shall be happy to be there as requested and will bring my diploma and other papers with me.</p>
                              <p>Sincerely,<br>-Jack</br></p>
                          </body>
                      </html>";
```

Ref: **[$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but `string interpolation` is way better than `concat`.

```
var name = "Susan";
var message = $"Dear Ms.{name}";
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: I like this one as well but can I combine the "@" with the "$" in front of a string?

Comment: @DenisSchaf sure you can, check out my answer.